# Delete duplicate member group in user account

Tags: powershell, active-directory, duplicates

In my company, I have a PowerShell script to copy group from one user to another. But it happens that I have two groups which one *Denied access* and the other *Allow acces*.
For example, after copying, I could have that in the user account :

```
FIC-LSM-APP-BO5-DND
FIC-LSM-APP-BO5-MAJ
```

I would like to delete the *Denied access* group with a script.

Here my code:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.VisualBasic')

$nomuser = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox("Login de >l'utilisateur à traiter", "A traiter", "")
$nommodele = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox("Nom du  >modèle", "Modèle", "")

try {
    $user = Get-ADUser -Identity $nomuser -Properties memberOf
} catch {
    [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Utilisateur $nomuser non >trouvé","Erreur",[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons]::OK,[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon]::Error)
    exit
}

try {
    $usertemplate = Get-ADUser -Identity $nommodele -Properties memberOf
} catch {
    [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("Utilisateur modèle $nomuser >non trouvé","Erreur",[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons]::OK,[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon]::Error)
    exit
}

$Groups = $User.MemberOf | ForEach-Object {
    Get-ADGroup $_
}
$groups = $Usertemplate.MemberOf | ForEach-Object {
    Get-ADGroup $_
}

$Groups | ForEach-Object {
    Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $_ -Members $user
}

$user = Get-ADUser -Identity $nomuser -Properties memberOf
$user.MemberOf | Get-ADGroup |  
    Group-Object {$_.Name -replace '^(.*)-(?:DND|MAJ)$', '$1'} | 
    Where-Object { $_.Count -eq 2 } | Select-Object -Expand Group | 
    Remove-ADGroupMember -Members $user -Confirm:$false
$user.MemberOf | ogv -Title "Nouvelle liste d'appartenance pour $nomuser"
```

I finally have time and a test data base to perform this code.

However I have a problem. For example :

```
Groups of $nomuser : FIC-LSM-APP-BO5-DND
Group of $nommodele : FIC-LSM-APP-BO5-MAJ
```

When I run the code, the target user (`$nomuser`) haven't no more group... I think there is an error in the code, but where I don't know.

Comment: Show us what you have tried, explain what didn't work as expected, and we may be able to help you with that. Writing the entire script for you? Not likely to happen.

Comment: Hi Ansgar, what a welcome answer :) I don't expected to have the entire script, I just want to understand and keep going on my script... So, that my script for copying rights from a user to another :

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Group-Object`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849907.aspx) to determine whether a user is member of both allow and deny group. The cmdlet allows you to specify custom matching criteria in a scriptblock, so you can remove a trailing `-DND` or `-MAJ` from the group name and group by the group "basename":

```
$user.MemberOf | Get-ADGroup |
    Group-Object {$_.Name -replace '^(.*)-(?:dnd|maj)$', '$1'}
```

Use `Where-Object` to filter the result for groups with a count of 2 and expand the `Group` property to get the original AD groups:

```
... | Where-Object { $_.Count -eq 2 } | Select-Object -Expand Group | ...
```

Use another `Where-Object` filter to restrict the groups to just the ones you want to remove the user from (e.g. with a filter `Name -like '*-dnd'`), then remove the user from those groups:

```
... | Remove-ADGroupMember -Members $user -Confirm:$false
```

Comment: Hi Ansgar, many thanks for your answer ! :) However, I have a little problem that I don't understand, when I write the following code, I have nothing : `$user.MemberOf | Get-ADGroup | 
    Group-Object {$_.Name -replace '^(.*)-(?:DND|MAJ)$', '$1'} | 
    Where-Object { $_.Count -eq 2 } | Select-Object -Expand Group | 
    Where-Object { $_.Name -like '*-DND' } | Select-Object -Expand Group | ogv -Title "Doulbon"`

Comment: What is the use of : `| Select-Object -Expand Group`

Comment: @NickOlas Basically, `Group-Object` creates objects with 3 properties: `Count` (the number of grouped items), `Name` (the property by which the items were grouped) and `Group` (containing a list of the original items, in your case AD groups). The first `Select-Object -Expand Group` expands the `Group` property so that you get the original AD groups. The second `Select-Object -Expand Group` tries to expand a (non-existing) `Group` property of these AD groups and thus doesn't produce output, so there's nothing for `Out-GridView` to display.

Comment: OK thanks for your explanations Ansgar ! As soon as I tried the script of a test data base, I come back :) Thanks again

Comment: Hi Ansgar, could you help me ? The code doesn't work... 0
down vote
accept
 

I finally have time and a test data base to perform this code.

However I have a problem. For example :

    Groups of $nomuser : FIC-LSM-APP-BO5-DND
    Group of $nommodele : FIC-LSM-APP-BO5-MAJ

When I run the code, the target user ($nomuser) haven't no more Group... I think there is an error in the code but where I don't know I'm not a specialist of powershell

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Edit your question and show your modified code as well as the expected and actual results.

Comment: @NickOlas You didn't remove the "allow" group(s) after expanding the group pair(s), so your code removes the user from both groups. Please re-read the last paragraph of my answer.

Comment: Hi Ansgar, thanks for your answer, I have to remove what in this code : ? :                                                                                           $user.MemberOf | Get-ADGroup |  
    Group-Object {$_.Name -replace '^(.*)-(?:DND|MAJ)$', '$1'} | 
    Where-Object { $_.Count -eq 2 } | Select-Object -Expand Group | 
    Remove-ADGroupMember -Members $user -Confirm:$false                                                                                                             Sorry for my questions :)

Comment: You have to *add* code that *removes* the groups you don't want removed from the list of groups that are removed.

Comment: ahhhh ok ! thanks ! :) and could you help me doing that ?

Comment: Please re-read my answer. It already contains all information you need. Pay particular attention to the last paragraph.

Comment: Hi Ansgar, I still don't understand what I have to do ... I'm sorry

Comment: After `... | Select-Object -Expand Group` you have a list of groups that contains both the DND and MAJ groups where the user is member of both of the groups. `Remove-ADGroupMember` removes the user from all of the groups, but since you only want to remove them from the MAJ groups you need to remove the DND groups from the list before calling `Remove-ADGroupMember`. This can be achieved by putting another `Where-Object` filter between `Select-Object -Expand Group` and `Remove-ADGroupMember`. What is so hard to understand about this?